# R: are there built-in functions to sort lists?

Tags: r, list

in R I have produced the following list `L`:

```
>L
[[1]]
[1] "A" "B" "C"  

[[2]]
[1] "D"  

[[3]]
[1] NULL
```

I would like to manipulate the list  `L` arriving at a database `df` like

```
>df
    df[,1] df[,2]
       "A"      1 
       "B"      1
       "C"      1 
       "D"      2
```

where the 2nd column gives the position in the list  `L` of the corresponding element in column 1. 
My question is: is(are) there a() built-in R function(s) which can do this manipulation quickly? I can do it using "brute force", but my solution does not scale well when I consider much bigger lists.

I thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll get a `warning` because of your `NULL` value, but you can use `stack` if you give your list items `names`:

```
L <- list(c("A", "B", "C"), "D", NULL)
stack(setNames(L, seq_along(L)))
#   values ind
# 1      A   1
# 2      B   1
# 3      C   1
# 4      D   2
# Warning message:
# In stack.default(setNames(L, seq_along(L))) :
#   non-vector elements will be ignored
```

If the `warning` displeases you, you can, of course, run `stack` on the non-`NULL` elements, but do it after you name your list elements so that the "ind" column reflects the correct value.

I'll show in 2 steps just for clarity:

```
names(L) <- seq_along(L)
stack(L[!sapply(L, is.null)])
```

Similarly, if you've gotten rid of the `NULL` list elements, you can use `melt` from "reshape2". You don't gain anything in brevity, and I'm not sure that you gain anything in efficiency either, but I thought I'd share it as an option.

```
library(reshape2)
names(L) <- seq_along(L)
melt(L[!sapply(L, is.null)])
```

Comment: `stack` does the job; thank you very much! I did not know it :-)

Answer (score 2):

Ananda's answer is seemingly better than this, but I'll put it up anyway:

```
> cbind(unlist(L), rep(1:length(L), sapply(L, length)))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "A"  "1" 
[2,] "B"  "1" 
[3,] "C"  "1" 
[4,] "D"  "2"
```

Comment: Thank you  @Thomas for your answer; appreciated.